# Partial evaluation of expression template

Tags: tensor, numerical-methods, expression-templates

I'm planing on writing a 3D-SEM library, in which I need to evaluate expressions such as:

```
integral(mesh, f*v);
```

With f a function and v is a *test function*.
The expression f*v can effectively be rewritten as a rank 6 tensor:

[image: T_{i,j,k,\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k}} := v_{i}(x_{\hat{i}}) v_{j}(x_{\hat{j}}) v_{k}(x_{\hat{k}}) f(x_{\hat{i}}, x_{\hat{j}}, x_{\hat{k}})]

and the integral is then a tensor reduction:

[image: b_{i,j,k} := \sum_{\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k}} w_{\hat{i}} v_{i}(x_{\hat{i}}) w_{\hat{j}} v_{j}(x_{\hat{j}}) w_{\hat{k}} v_{k}(x_{\hat{k}}) f(x_{\hat{i}}, x_{\hat{j}}, x_{\hat{k}})]

This can be evaluated quickly in three steps:

[image: partial eval]

The math are quite simple, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.
Are there some tensor library that are able to perform similar things ?

Alternatively, are there articles I could read that could give me some pointers on how to implement this ?

Thanks in advance